# Selected for select option menu if condition is met in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

```
<select ng-model="item.value" ng-options="item.name for item in items">
</select>
```

The above will populate select option in AngularJS, but how can I add `selected` if my condition is met?

I want to do something like this:

```
<select ng-model="item.value" ng-options="item.name for item in items" if="item.name == someValueToCheckAgainst" selected endif>
</select>
```

Obviously the above is wrong, but I was trying to search for this to see if it is possible to do.

This is items

```
var items = [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ];
var someValueToCheckAgainst = 'b';
```

so my menu should be like this

```
<select ng-model="item.value">
  <option value="a">a</option>
  <option value="b" selected>a</option>
  <option value="c">a</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I can't quite get what ‘ng-model="item.value"‘ supposed to do

Comment: @Ali sure that all options should have the same value?

Comment: @peaceman oops sorry :P

Comment: @Ali you just have to exchange item.value with someValueToCheckAgainst in your example above

Comment: @peaceman @d_z I think what I'm trying to do is that when the page first load I want to keep the `selected` option in the item that was pulled from the database (which I have it available in the scope) and then when we submit the form it should just send that to the model from their select item.

Comment: @Ali have you seen my example on codepen, that i posted under my answer?

Comment: 1. If you want your select to have selected attribute set based on SomeValueToCheckAgainst, than what the application has to do if you manually set option a? Does it have to change SomeValueToCheck? Or it must prohibit you to change the value?  2. Your items objects don' t have neither value, nor name.

Comment: @peaceman yes I did and I'm trying to see if I can change it to make it work in my example

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just figured this out

```
<select ng-model="form.model">
  <option ng-selected="{{item == valueToCheckAgainst}}"
          ng-repeat="item in items"
          value="{{item}}">
          {{item}}
  </option>
</select>
```

Comment: I'm glad you figured out. Have you figured out also why my and @peaceman solution (basically the same) didn't work? Just wonder.

Comment: this is what was missing @d_z `ng-selected="{{item == valueToCheckAgainst}}`

Comment: But that's what `ng-model` of `<select>` is for - to bind selected value to it. As it's two-way binding, you can set and change it. The bound property of the `model` will always reflect the currently selected value. So when you set `ng-model` to `someValueToCheckAgainst`, it's value will always be the same as value of the currently selected option, and vice-versa!

Comment: ah sorry that one is suppose to be the model name for the form to be submitted. I guess I wasn't clear about that part from the beginning.

Comment: I want to add if the programmatically changed ng-model value doesn't update UI, use **track by topic.id** in ng-options

Answer (score 4):

For me this statement makes no sense.

```
<select ng-model="item.value" ng-options="item.name for item in items"> </select>
```

ng-model is current value (bound model). If your 'item' looks like ’{ value, name }' than you should define your 'select' as

```
<select ng-model="someValueToCheckAgainst" ng-options="item.value as item.name for item in items"> </select>
```

Comment: Sorry my question might not be clear, but the code I have above works, but I'm trying to do the `if` condition for `selected` not the `select` menu

Comment: @Ali, could you please provide more details on your 'items' object than and what you want to achieve?

Comment: Thanks for the help :) +1 for you

Answer (score 1):

The selected option is defined by the value of the ng-model attribute. For further information you can take a look at the official documentation https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select.

Comment: I'm trying to see how can I use ngSelected to acheive what I'm tryind to go above... but it seems a bit confusing as to what exactly it is expected there and I'm also using the code above which is a bit difference.

Comment: @peaceman, You are right of course, but I find this specific article absolutely terrible for understanding :) especially the case mentioned by OP

Comment: @Ali take a look at the following example
http://codepen.io/peaceman/pen/uLDty
this might help you

Comment: Thanks for the help :) +1 for you

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use **ng-option directive** instead of ng-repeat for select boxes, beacuse ng-option is specifically created for select box and handles options in best way. And how we can set a default or conditional option value selected in ng-option directive is using **ng-init** directive with it like this:

```
<select ng-model="item.value" 
        ng-options="item.name for item in items" 
        ng-init="condition ? item.value = items[opt index] : item.value = items[0]">
</select>
```

Comment: I want to set a default option of "Searching..." for my select while data is fetched from a server.  Original code uses `ng-if` and 2 select elements, but both selects show due to the api call (only want 1). `<select ng-if="object.names !== null" id="obj-name" type="text" class="input-group__input" ng-model="response.object.id" ng-options="object.id as object.name for object in object.names" ng-change="object.saveName()"></select>` Could you show using `ng-init` in [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55423562/ng-if-showing-both-elements-during-asynchronous-call)?